# How to assign values to more than one variable from set of files using batch for loop?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I am trying to call a batch script with parameter, from another script. I have two txt files containing list of PC IP addresses and list of services to check running on those PCs. I am planning this will remotely check service status or file exists on bulk of PCs. What I have tried, main.bat contains:

```
for /f %%i %%j in (PCList.txt FileList.txt) do call anotherscript.bat %%i %%j
```

definitely it should not work as there is nothing like this in for man page, I know. what I am trying, use two variables that will hold two values from two files respectively  and call anotherscript.bat with two parameters. I am able to play with one variable and one file. anotherscript.bat contains:

```
psexec.exe \\%1 -s IF EXIST "%2" ( echo File exist : %2 >>"%~dp0\logs.txt" )
```

FileList.txt contains

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144"
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin"
```

PCList.txt contains

```
LANS14118815
LANS14118816
```

Is there any workaround? Please support. Thanks

Comment: Please provide some explicit examples.

Comment: for /f %%i in (PCList.txt FileList.txt) do call anotherscript.bat %%i. anotherscript.bat contains: psexec.exe \\%1 -s IF EXIST "%2" (
echo File exist           : C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144>>"%~dp0\logs.txt" ).

Comment: 1. [Edit] your question and put code there! 2. Learn how to [format code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a method to read from two files in parallel. This is possible by using two methods at the same time (`<file1 set /p` and `for /f ... in (file2)`):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

<pclist.txt (
  for /f "delims=" %%a in (filelist.txt) do (
    set /p out=
    ECHO call anotherscript.bat "!out!" "%%~a"
  )
)
```

Remove the `ECHO`, if the output is what you need.